# How to NULL out a 'no-break space' character in Redshift Copy Command?

Tags: unicode, amazon-redshift

My `COPY` command keeps receiving the following error:

`Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x73 found at location 4194303`

I ran it through the following function to check for non-ASCII characters:

```
def return_non_ascii_codes(input: str):
    for char in input:
        if ord(char) > 127:
            yield ord(char)
```

And found out that I had a number of characters that returned a `160` code.  Looking this up in a `Unicode` chart, it looks like this is a `non-break space` character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

I want to `NULL` these characters out in my `COPY` command, but am unsure of what the correct character sequence/format I should use.

The `COPY` command is as follows:

```
COPY xxx
FROM 's3://xxx/cleansed.csv'
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx'
-- GZIP
ESCAPE
FILLRECORD
TRIMBLANKS
TRUNCATECOLUMNS
DELIMITER '|'
BLANKSASNULL
REMOVEQUOTES
ACCEPTINVCHARS
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
DATEFORMAT 'auto';
```

EDIT:
I used Python to find the characters, but Python does not do any of the actual processing in my pipeline.  I do a `COPY TO STDOUT` command from our `PostgreSQL` databases, and then upload those files directly to `S3` for copy to `Redshift`.  So it needs to be handled in one of those two places.

Here are the two fields from the destination table:

```
id                      BIGINT,
quiz_data               VARCHAR(65535)
```

UPDATE 1:
I ran the script through a function to cleanse all non-ASCII characters like so:

```
with open(file, 'r') as inf, open(outfile, 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            print(return_non_ascii_codes(line))
            outf.write(''.join(return_ascii_chars(line)))

def return_ascii_chars(input: str):
    return (char for char in input if ord(char) < 127)
```

and then tried to `COPY` to Redshift.  Still getting the following:

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x20 found at location 4194303
```

I've double-checked that the cleansed file doesn't have any non-ASCII character...

Answer (score 1):

```
COPY table1 FROM 's3://my_bucket' CREDENTIALS '' ACCEPTINVCHARS
```

Use can use ACCEPTINVCHARS parameter in your copy command.

Its pretty easy and straight forward. 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: The `ACCEPTINVCHARS` doesn't work, I have that included in my command already.

Comment: @flybonzai - Did you try "null as '\0' " parameter in your copy command?

Comment: Yes, I did that as well

Comment: Can you post the sample data and your copy command along with the question please.

Comment: I've added the `COPY`, the field itself is a 4.7 million character `YAML` string.... it's a beast

Comment: I dont see null as '\0' . If you have already tried, what was the error message you got? Same?

Comment: yeah, it was the same.  Sorry, I removed it after it didn't work the first time.  I tried both `\0` and `\000`

Answer (score 0):

yourvariable.replace(unichr(160), "")

Comment: It's never running through Python though.  It goes straight from a PostgreSQL `COPY TO STDOUT` command into an S3 file, and then is loaded into Redshift.  So I need to handle it on either the Redshift or PostgreSQL side.

Comment: Then why is this tagged python :)?

Comment: Just due to having some `python` in the OP.

Comment: That isn't how tags work.  You should remove the python tag.

Comment: It's been removed.